# To fill the series of line chart with other json data format

Tags: json, charts, highcharts, linechart

I'm using highchart.js for present my data to line chart and I have such kind of json data

[image]

[image]

[image]

And I have to fill my line chart series. How can I do that more understandable? Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please show your own effort to be helped with. For easier help you might add your json as text and you could use an external tool (like [jsfiddle](jsfiddle.net) for a working example.

Comment: Thank you bro, I found out it :)